# The namenode how to find empty datanode?

Tags: hadoop, namespaces, client

The namenode how to find empty datanode?
When a client makes a request to write datanodes . 
By which algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is pretty complicated.  In most cases, as a user of Hadoop or even an administrator of HDFS, you probably don't need to care exactly how the NameNode determines which node(s) to write its blocks to.  However, if you're really curious, take a look at the following resources:

From the Hadoop Definitive Guide's '[Anatomy of a File Write](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-3/data-flow)':

> The client creates the file by calling create() on
>   DistributedFileSystem (step 1 in Figure 3-3). DistributedFileSystem
>   makes an RPC call to the namenode to create a new file in the
>   filesystem’s namespace, with no blocks associated with it (step 2).
>   The namenode performs various checks to make sure the file doesn’t
>   already exist, and that the client has the right permissions to create
>   the file. If these checks pass, the namenode makes a record of the new
>   file; otherwise, file creation fails and the client is thrown an
>   IOException. The DistributedFileSystem returns an FSDataOutputStream
>   for the client to start writing data to. Just as in the read case,
>   FSDataOutputStream wraps a DFSOutputStream, which handles
>   communication with the datanodes and namenode.
>
> As the client writes data (step 3), DFSOutputStream splits it into
>   packets, which it writes to an internal queue, called the data queue.
>   The data queue is consumed by the DataStreamer, whose responsibility
>   it is to ask the namenode to allocate new blocks by picking a list of
>   suitable datanodes to store the replicas. The list of datanodes forms
>   a pipeline—we’ll assume the replication level is three, so there are
>   three nodes in the pipeline. The DataStreamer streams the packets to
>   the first datanode in the pipeline, which stores the packet and
>   forwards it to the second datanode in the pipeline. Similarly, the
>   second datanode stores the packet and forwards it to the third (and
>   last) datanode in the pipeline.

You can also check out the source code from the latest stable ASF Hadoop if you want to step through it:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem.java#L346

Comment: Thanking you jtravaglini